# How to make SOAP call using native SoapClient in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I want to make a call to web service, which is also under development, and which has one function defined within WSDL, PlaceInvoiceFromStream. Function defines one argument to be passed, Invoice. WSDL imports types defined within XSD shema.

WSDL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions name ="inService"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsdl="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:tns="http://localhost/ebiz/ws/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    targetNamespace="http://localhost/ebiz/ws/">
    <import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
        location="http://localhost/ebiz/ws/Invoice.xsd"
    />
    <message name="getPlaceInvoiceInput">
        <part name="body" element="xsdl:Invoice"/>
    </message>
    <message name="getPlaceInvoiceOutput">
        <part name="body" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="inServicePortType">
        <operation name="PlaceInvoiceFromStream">
            <input message="tns:getPlaceInvoiceInput"/>
            <output message="tns:getPlaceInvoiceOutput"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="inServiceBinding" type="tns:inServicePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="PlaceInvoiceFromStream">
            <soap:operation soapAction="PlaceInvoiceFromStream"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="inService">
        <port name="inServicePort" binding="tns:inServiceBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/ebiz/ws/soapServer.php"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Schema looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDataTypes-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:udt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnqualifiedDataTypes-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.1">
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.1.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.1.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnqualifiedDataTypes-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-UnqualifiedDataTypes-2.1.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.1.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDataTypes-2" schemaLocation="../common/UBL-QualifiedDataTypes-2.1.xsd"/>
<xsd:element name="Invoice" type="InvoiceType"/>
<xsd:complexType name="InvoiceType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="ext:UBLExtensions"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:UBLVersionID"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:CustomizationID" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:ProfileID" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:ID"></xsd:element>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:CopyIndicator" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:IssueDate"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:InvoiceTypeCode" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:Note" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:TaxPointDate" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:AccountingCost" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cbc:LineCountNumeric" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:InvoicePeriod" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:OrderReference" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:DespatchDocumentReference" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:ReceiptDocumentReference" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:ContractDocumentReference" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:AdditionalDocumentReference" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:Signature" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:AccountingSupplierParty"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:AccountingCustomerParty"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:BuyerCustomerParty" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:SellerSupplierParty" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:TaxRepresentativeParty" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:Delivery" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:DeliveryTerms" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:PaymentMeans" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:PaymentTerms" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:PrepaidPayment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:AllowanceCharge" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:TaxTotal" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:LegalMonetaryTotal"/>
        <xsd:element ref="cac:InvoiceLine" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

UBL 2.1 Schemas: http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/prd2-UBL-2.1/UBL-2.1.html#SCHEMAS

Invoice is complex data, saved in XML file, and which contains namespaces and attributes. It starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice
 xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
 xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
 xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2"
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://localhost/ebiz/ws/Invoice.xsd"
 xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
 xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <cbc:ID>INVOICE1</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Name>InvoiceIssuePlaceData</cbc:Name>
            <ext:ExtensionAgencyURI>urn:invoice:issueplace</ext:ExtensionAgencyURI>
            <ext:ExtensionContent>
                <ext:InvoiceIssuePlace>MyCity</ext:InvoiceIssuePlace>
            </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:ID>01 1206-2406-568</cbc:ID>`
```

etc...

I have tried this approach:

```
// LOAD XML and TRANSFORM FOR SoapClient 
$xmlfile = "Invoice123.xml";
$xslfile = "xsltForSoapClientRequest.xsl";
$xmlDOM = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDOM->load($xmlfile);
$xslDOM = new DOMDocument();
$xslDOM->load($xslfile);
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xslDOM);
$transformedXML = $proc->transformToDoc($xmlDOM);
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_string($transformedXML);

// CREATE ARRAY
$xmlarr = xml2array($xmldoc->asXML());

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace'=>1));
$result=$client->PlaceInvoiceFromStream($xmlarr);
```

but with no success.

XSL transformation changes are:

- node attribute becomes node element
- complex node value becomes "_" element

xml2array changes are:

- attributes becomes separate array

So, $xmlarr to be sent to web service function is in the following form:

```
array(2) {
  ["Invoice"]=>
  array(15) {
    ["ext:UBLExtensions"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["ext:UBLExtension"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["cbc:ID"]=>
        string(10) "INVOICE1"
        ["cbc:Name"]=>
        string(21) "InvoiceIssuePlaceData"
        ["ext:ExtensionAgencyURI"]=>
        string(25) "urn:invoice:issueplace"
        ["ext:ExtensionContent"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["ext:InvoiceIssuePlace"]=>
          string(7) "MyCity"
        }
      }
    }
    ["cbc:UBLVersionID"]=>
    string(3) "2.1"
    ["cbc:ID"]=>
    string(16) "01 1206-2406-568"
...

  ["Invoice_attr"]=>
  array(8) {
    ["xmlns"]=>
    string(54) "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    ["xmlns:xsi"]=>
    string(41) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    ["xmlns:cac"]=>
    string(72) "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    ["xmlns:cbc"]=>
    string(68) "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    ["xmlns:sac"]=>
    string(75) "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2"
    ["xmlns:ext"]=>
    string(72) "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
    ["xmlns:sig"]=>
    string(72) "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2"
    ["xsi:schemaLocation"]=>
    string(93) "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://localhost/ebiz/ws/Invoice.xsd"
  }
}
```

The result of the web service call is:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'UBLExtensions' property
```

What should be the form for the correct SOAP request? What form of the array is expected for SOAP request? Does SOAP understands, based on WSDL and XSD, that "_" element? Or attributes in the separate array?

Thanks in advance for any help in fixing this issue...

## UPDATE:

changed wsdl:

```
<message name="getPlaceInvoiceInput">
    <part name="Invoice" element="xsdl:InvoiceType"/>
```

SoapClient accepts following request:

```
$xmlarr = array(
    "UBLExtensions"=>
    array(
      "UBLExtension"=>
      array(
        "ID"=>"INVOICE1",
        "Name"=>"InvoiceIssuePlaceData",
        "ExtensionAgencyURI"=>"urn:invoice:issueplace",
        "ExtensionContent"=>
        array(
          "InvoiceIssuePlace"=>"MyCity"
        )
      )
    ),
    "UBLVersionID"=>"2.1",
    "ID"=>"01 1206-2406-568",
    ...
```

which is not what I want. I need namespaces in keys. What should be changed/added to make SoapClient able to accepts namespaces within keys in the request array, like i.e. "ext:UBLExtensions"?

Comment: Can you add the WSDL & schema?  That's probably more helpful than a sample XML message.

Comment: WSDL and schema added...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to start your `array` at the `UBLExtensions` level, not the `Invoice` level.  It sees your top element as `Invoice` where it expects `UBLExtensions` and complains when it doesn't find it:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'UBLExtensions' property
```

It does not require the second `Invoice_attr` array, the names of the array elements go by the element names in the schema, not the `ref` values.  Look what the `ref` points to in your schema (you don't seem to list it), that `element` should have a `name`.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. Yes, you were right about array start at the UBLExtensions level. I have changed wsdl too. I got no error message now, but SoapClient expects array with keys which are without namespaces, while my xml file contains keys with namespaces. What should be changed/added to make SoapClient able to accepts namespaces within keys in the request array, like i.e. "ext:UBLExtensions"?

Comment: I think SoapClient will add the namespaces when it builds the request.  You're starting from XML, which is unusual.  SoapClient is meant to allow you to start from an array and serialize it to a SOAP request.  Check the request is sends (either through WireShark or `__getLastRequest`), you should see namespaces.